# In an asp.net WebAPI controller is this a reliable / suggested way to get whether http or https?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Below is a sample of my Index controller. I'm wondering if there is a better, more reliable way to get whether the traffic is https or not.

```
  public ActionResult IndexTest1(string year)
    {
        var isSecure = 
           ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
var isSecure = Request.RequestUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
```

inside a controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.IsSecureConnection` is the correct way to determine whether a request is made via HTTPS.

> **From MSDN:**
>
> Gets a value indicating whether the HTTP connection uses secure sockets (that is, HTTPS).
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx

**Edit:** The IsSecureConnection property is not available directly from the Request property of an ApiController.  You'll need to access an instance of the HttpContext object and use its Request property.

<del>If you want this value from your controller action, you don't need to reference ther HttpContext directly.

You can just use:

    var isSecure = Request.IsSecureConnection;

Where `Request` is a property in the controller's bar class.</del>

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not available in WebAPI

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  IsSecureConnection is not available via the Request property of System.Web.Http.Web.ApiController.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Be warned that if you use HttpContext then you are limited to WebHost.  SelfHost and Owin hosts do not have access to HttpContext.  I think it would be safer to look at the Request.RequestUri.Scheme.

Comment: I agree with DarrelMiller. Web API is designed to run inside different hosts. Accessing the System.Web.HttpContext intance would limit the project's portability.